# Long time for Image Feature Extraction using Wavelets

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, feature-extraction, wavelet-transform

I have a few directories each with 220 images (borders taken and denoised already) from which I need to extract features for ML. I wrote a python script that works with a directory of 6 images. Converts each image into a Numpy Array and uses the array to generate a Wavelet, using PyWavelets. The output file is a 17,2MB and takes about 4 minutes. Seems ok to me.

But when I run the same script (changing only the string parameters so the directory is the big one) it seems to stay in infinite loop or something. I realize that 220 images would take a a lot longer but the it is running for 2:30 hours and counting. Doesn't seem right. Plus, when I try to see the file size (via context menu), it changes between 2,2MB to 17,2MB and back to zero.

My real question is: Do I keep waiting?

The code:

```
def csv_writer(data, path):
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
    with open(path, "w", newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow(line)

def extractFeats():
    for image_path in os.listdir(path):
        input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
        image = io.imread(input_path)
        listOfArrays.append(image)
        coeffs = pywt.dwt2(image, 'haar')
        listOfCoeffs.append(coeffs)
        for element in listOfCoeffs:
            csv_writer(element,'trainTest.csv' )



Parallel(delayed(extractFeats()))
```

Notice that I am using joblib for paralellism. Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: The reason you see file size changing back and forth is probably because you use 'w' option in csv_writer. So you are overwriting the file every time. Instead you should be appending to the file. You are also opening/closing the file many times in the loop. So this is one potential cause of long run time. IO operations are time consuming.

Comment: Why are you writing the results into a csv file (the slowest possibility i can think of)? Simply writing to a binary file, or using h5py should be some orders of magnitudes faster.

Comment: I will check theese hints, thank you. But I discovered I am still using too much data. A image numpy array is too big, I must have a selection of it's data first